# Set insensitive-state icon for toolbar button in GTK

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, gtk

I am writing an app in C, using GTK library for interface. Right now, I have a window with a toolbar, containing 3 buttons. For these buttons I have used custom images instead of stock ones. My toolbar is shown below.

[image: toolbar whose buttons I'd like to change colors when disabled]

However, when I disable them by using `gtk_widget_set_sensitive()`, my icons don't change colors. I wasn't able to find anywhere in GTK docs where I can set a "disabled" icon state for these buttons. Is there any place I can specify an icon for a disabled button state?

Answer (score 1):

How did you create these tool buttons? I am assuming a `GtkToolItem` containing a `GtkImage`? The easiest way is to listen to the [`state-flags-changed`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-state-flags-changed) signal and change the contents of the `GtkImage` based on the state flags. That way you can handle not only the insensitive state, but also the prelight (mouseover), pressed, etc.

Comment: Yep, they're `GtkToolItem`s that I set a `GtkImage` as icon. I'm going to test this approach.

Comment: I implemented this approach but now my icons don't show when I change them.

Comment: Are you sure that you are changing the `GtkImage` correctly?

Comment: Yep. I tried allocating them in advance and then just using the pointers, but that didn't work because GTK seems to deallocate images when unneeded. Then I tried creating the icons in the moment I was going to change them, but this failed as well. The icon disappears and then GTK throws an assertion failure error.

Comment: Then I think you should investigate the assertion failure. It generally means a programmer error. I don't think I can give you any more advice without seeing your code ;-)

Comment: I'm aware of that. Unfortunately I lost too much time trying to narrow this problem and ended reverting my code and giving up these icons for now.